# Getting addition of all specific vlaues of classes in a list in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is the structure;

I want to get the sum of all the amounts
Bills[
BillStatement(amount:20, date'24/07/2020'),
BillStatement(amount:30, date'24/07/2020'),
BillStatement(amount:10, date'24/07/2020'),
]

Answer (score 0):

```
final bills = [
  BillStatement(amount:20, date:'24/07/2020'),
  BillStatement(amount:30, date:'24/07/2020'),
  BillStatement(amount:10, date:'24/07/2020'),
];

num totalAmount = 0;
bills.forEach((billStatement) => totalAmount += billStatement.amount);

print(totalAmount);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
getItemTotal(List<BillStatement> bills){
    double sum= 0.0;
    bills.forEach((e) {
    sum += e.amount;
    }
    
    return sum;
    }
```